# HTTPError when using urllib2 read()

Tags: python, urllib2, http-error

I'm trying to scrape a web page using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup. It was working fine and then when I put in an `input()` in a different part of my code to try and debug something, I got an HTTPError. When I tried running my program again, I got an HTTPError when trying calling read(). The error stack is below:

```
[2013-07-17 16:47:07,415: ERROR/MainProcess] Task program.tasks.testTask[460db7cf-ff58-4a51-9c0f-749affc66abb] raised exception: IOError()
16:47:07 celeryd.1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/Users/username/folder/server2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 181, in trace_task
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/Users/username/folder/server2/program/tasks.py", line 193, in run
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     self.get_top_itunes_game_by_genre(genre)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/Users/username/folder/server2/program/tasks.py", line 244, in get_top_itunes_game_by_genre
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     game_page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(game_url).read())
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     response = meth(req, response)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     return self._call_chain(*args)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     result = func(*args)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
16:47:07 celeryd.1 |     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
16:47:07 celeryd.1 | HTTPError
```

Here's the code:

```
for game_url in urls:    
    game_page = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(game_url).read())
    # code to process page
```

Does anyone know why I started getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: `HTTPError`s are generally returned when something fails either on the network level or the server side. Consider trying to open whatever URL you think you're opening in a browser and seeing if it works there.

Comment: urllib2 is going to throw some errors sooner or later (you probably got a 40x response), you should probably be prepared to catch them.

Comment: looks like some of the pages just aren't loading for some reason, which is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Changing my comment into an answer:

The page that you're scraping responded with (most likely) a 4xx response, and urllib2 raises an HTTPError, as it says it does in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).  It is your job to catch that exception and (hopefully) do something with it, log it or what have you.  Your traceback doesn't display the code/reason for the HTTPError for whatever reason, but it is there.  Look at the 'code' and 'reason' attributes of the error.

editorial:
It is possible that the website that you were scraping figured out that you're a robot.  You might want to take a moment to rewrite your scraper to use a more server-friendly (and vastly better API) library.  urllib2 is fine for one-off tasks but it has numerous shortcomings that I won't get into here.  Possible superior libraries to look at are [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/), maybe [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).  All have up/downsides so I can't tell you the one that's right for your needs.

You also may want to look at what user-agent header you're sending with your requests, since if you self-identify as a robot, well.  Yeah.

Comment: if i just want to be able to open and read a large number of websites which one would you recommend?

Comment: start with requests, it has the most reasonable API.