# Python Beautiful Soup and Urllib 403 Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib, http-status-code-403

I'm using Python 2.7.5 with BeautifulSoap4 and urllib to extract (a lot of) data from lyrics websites and store them into an XML file. The code works well  until a mysterious point where Python seems to enter a phase of continuous work without making any progress and without throwing errors. After quitting Python, if I try to access the lyrics website I get this Error:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried with two different websites and I got the same error in the end.

Also Python is no more able to extract data from that website unless i use a proxy

Is there a way I can fix this?

Thanks!!

Comment: The website you were scraping figured out you are a robot, and stopped you accordingly.  I'd wager you're not following the site's robots.txt, for one.  And you're freely self-identifying with your user-agent header as a robot, for two.

Comment: So you suggest I should insert some header info to tell the server I'm a web browser or something else?

Comment: Ideally, you would do that, and a few other things to be as nice to the server as possible - it's just courtesy.  You should probably use a different library, like mechanize or requests.  urllib is notorious for being _mean_ on servers - there's some web standards that it doesn't follow, at least out-of-the-box.  See my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712282/httperror-when-using-urllib2-read/17712696#17712696

Comment: So request would be good for reading HTML BeautifulSoup could parse?  May you tell me what piece of code i should write in substitution to urllib.open(url) after importing request library?

Comment: I would direct you to the requests documentation, it is very easy to read and follow.  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#user-guide

Comment: Ok, thank you. But if I have to replace urllib.open, do you think that mechanize.open is the best solution?

Comment: In the end I got the same 403 Error using mechanize.urlopen(mechanize.Request("some url")). Do I have to provide any additional header info?